# SQLAlchemy-1.4.21 SQL Server pyodbc connection error

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlalchemy, runtime-error, pyodbc

When connecting to a SQL Server DB using the latest SQLAlchemy release I get the following error "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)", using a previous version - works fine.

Code:

> engine =
> sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@{server}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes")

In version 'SQLAlchemy-1.3.22' this works fine.
But in version 'SQLAlchemy-1.4.21', I get a horribly long error.

Has anybody else come across this, does anyone know the reason and/or fix (other than just using the old release version)?

Comment: Remove the `?trusted_connection=yes` from the end of the connection URI.